# How to target mobile devices to a project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, mobile

I got solution now in Visual Studio with 2 web projects. One default, and one i would like to target if the user is using a mobile device.

I would like to check if the user is on a mobile device when entering the default site, www.site.com, then redirect to the m.site.com.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[1]**

In ASP.NET, you can easily detect the mobile device request using `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` property and `Request.UserAgent`.

The following code checks the `IsMobileDevice` property and redirects to the mobile specific page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
    {
       Response.Redirec("~/default_mobile.aspx");          
    }
}
```

**[2]**

Another better method is to use open source project called `51Degrees`.  Here is an [article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Mobile-Device-Detection-and-Redirection-Using-ASP-NET.aspx) about  how to use it in your application.